# How can i configurate the emqtt`s max packet size

Tags: emq

I send the large data (about 50MB),And i add the `mqtt.max_packet_size` value as `6400KB` ,But still report below error info .from https://docs.emqx.io/docs/broker/v3/cn/config.html#mqtt  it shows that this value as `mqtt.max_packet_size = 1MB`, I am not sure this value can be add more because i need to send large data .
Please advice.thanks

current config:

```
//Max Packet Size Allowed, 64K by default.

mqtt.max_packet_size = 6400KB
```

emqtt version info as below:

```
[root@proxy bin]# ./emqttd_ctl status
Node 'emqttd@127.0.0.1' is started
emqttd 2.2 is running
```

error log

```
2020-05-21 11:30:55.859 [error] <0.17448.21>@emqttd_client:received:328 Client(127.0.0.1:59748): Framing error - invalid_mqtt_frame_len
```

Answer (score 0):

6400KB？ 6400KB == 5MB

Try 64000 KB or 128MB